# Rename features in TensorFlow estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using a canned estimator and read data from a source that I cannot control. The source stores the features with snake_case, whereas what I give the predict function always comes in camelCase and is also beyond my control.

Roughly, I train the model and export it, so I can read that later on:

```
features = ... # snake_case
estimator = tf.estimator(DNNClassifier(feature_columns=features, ...)
...
estimator.export_savedmodel(...)
```

Is there a way to rename the features (from snake to camel case) either when I train the model (as an alias or something like it) or afterwards when I save it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

https://gist.github.com/batzner/7c24802dd9c5e15870b4b56e22135c96

They rename the variables stored in a checkpoint after iterating through the variables returned by `tf.contrib.framework.list_variables()`

Comment: `list_variables()` actually gives me

    [('dnn/hiddenlayer_0/bias', [10]),
     ('dnn/hiddenlayer_0/bias/t_0/Adagrad', [10]),
     ('dnn/hiddenlayer_0/kernel', [5, 10]),
     ('dnn/hiddenlayer_0/kernel/t_0/Adagrad', [5, 10]),
     ('dnn/logits/bias', [1]),
     ('dnn/logits/bias/t_0/Adagrad', [1]),
     ('dnn/logits/kernel', [10, 1]),
     ('dnn/logits/kernel/t_0/Adagrad', [10, 1]),
     ('global_step', [])]



That doesn't look like any of the features in my model. I ran it after the training finished.

Comment: The output for `estimator.get_variable_names()` is identical to `tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(estimator.model_dir)` and does not appear to include the features.

Comment: You can also use tf.train.list_variables() (no need to use the contrib package that will be removed in TF 2.0)